# Why is shower wall cracking (tile and grout)?

Tags: shower, grout, ceramic-tile

Shower was redone about a year ago. At some point a crack slowly developed, through grout and a tile. The area is in the middle section, so tiles above and below and to the sides are fine.

What could be the cause? Is everything around it under strain, and it just erupted in the middle?

image below - red lines added over cracks

EDIT: another image with 3 steps - studs, cement board + redgard, start tiling

Also, I should say there are a few other grout cracks in various places. Bathroom is at corner of house, so it's an outside wall.

The reason for remodel was original drywall got wet and bulgy from soap holder falling off (and us not covering it up very well). Studs were a little moldy but seemed sturdy enough. Cleaned with vinegar and dried for a few days.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd have to tell us something about what's behind the tile.

Comment: Well either there is no waterproof membrane and concrete board wasn't used or you have some huge settling issues with your house.     It could be from a loose tile to thinset join but not usually in a fault pattern like this.   If I were to guess I would say either the wall wasn't prepared right at all - could be too much distance between studs (doubt it) maybe there is just drywall behind and the drywall got wet and cracked because of that.    That sort of cracking is not a good sign.    Also is this wall on the outside of the house?

Comment: Could be they used cement board but didn't do the joints correctly.  That's moot: it needs to be redone and redone right.

Comment: Really do need more information about whether this is caused by the house settling/heaving. Is this an exterior wall? Are you on a hill? Is there clay under the house? Has it rained or been dry a lot lately? Do other doors around the house bind seasonally?

Comment: @aquaticapetheory - The cracked tile does seem to be over the cement boards seam. Is the problem that they are not flush? Or that they would buckle out over time? Does it need blocking along the seam for extra screws?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The bathroom is on the corner in the backyard. It's possible it could be foundation related, but before that was original (as far as I know?) tile that didn't have any cracked tiles for ~40 years.

Comment: @itchyback - Did you install the cement boards horizontally or vertically?  If you did the former, there should be no vertical seam, except at the corners.

Comment: Sometimes foundation issues start for no apparent reason. Just off the top of my head, changes in gutters/drainage, changes in the water table, the city fixed the leaking water main nearby, climate chaos... I'd look at the foundation and the exterior finish to see if there's any hint. If you're going to re-do entirely, look at Kerdi products as a decoupler. (As an aside, please tell us that electrical stuff in the picture didn't just get buried in the wall.)

Comment: That's a outlet for shaving while in the shower <wink>.

Comment: @SteveSh The cement boards have a horizontal seam.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The electrical wiring is indeed buried in the wall. The main electrical panel is on the outside of the bathroom wall. Is that against code?

Comment: From the picture, it looked like a junction box. If it is a junction and it isn’t accessible, then yes — that’s not to code. If it’s a junction box that faces the exterior and is accessible, then you’re fine.

Comment: @itchmyback The cement boards must be joined together to form a monolithic base for the tile.  This means finishing the seam joints and corners with tile setting mortar and special (not drywall) mesh tape.  Fastener heads need to be finished too.  From the pictures, it looks like you need to redo the whole thing.  I recommend you consult [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Setting-Tile-Revised-Updated-Homebuilding/dp/1561580805), [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Tile-Your-World-Bridges-Setting/dp/0974275433), and the [John Bridge Forums](https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/).

Comment: @aquaticapetheory - Agreed.  But the cement board is laid horizontally, with a horizontal seam, so there should be no vertical joints in the cement board.  Nothing I've heard explain the vertical cracks in the tile, except for gross settling or twisting of the wall.

Comment: @itchmyback - Is it possible the wall is bulging out in the center of the wall, where the cracking is happening?  You might want to lay a good straight edge (4' or 5' level would be ideal) along the wall to make sure its flat.

Comment: @SteveSh Making it monolithic will reduce flexing.  That sheet of cement board is fixed to the studs but it's free to flop around between them.  Source of the flexing could be the tub flexing or shifting around under the user's weight because it's not fixed solidly enough.  Wouldn't take much.  Don't have enough information from the pictures and verbiage.  Also, doesn't matter if the wall is bulging, you can set tile on a curved surface if it's solid and doesn't move.

Comment: @SteveSh The wall bulges out slightly around the cracked area, so horizontally and vertically (all directions really). Maybe the wall was not completely flush when my contractor put the tiles on, and then the wall got worse in that area over time?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is it is called flexing. The bad news is it is flexing.

The wall behind it was not done properly and it is flexing. If the tiles are on a drywall it will do that. It should have been a cement board. The grouts are the weakest point, but I have seen tiles crack as well, like you have. That is a clear indicator of flexing. More damage is to come.

Comment: In my house, it's not only just greenboard, but no joint tape was used between pieces.